# javascript and (&&) operator not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I need to check if a string is equal to a defined value AND if the object has the `hash` key.

I am very confused with this:

```
var my_string = 'some_string';
var my_obj = {'hash':'4010f89a05c236cd4f3a5c7558af0e70dc4216454d2d5155a285bfbad752ce51f9510272821a254'}
console.log((my_string == 'some_string' && my_obj['hash']));
```

That return `4010f89a05c236cd4f3a5c7558af0e70dc4216454d2d5155a285bfbad752ce51f9510272821a254`

Expected `true` or `false` (in this example expected `true`).

Comment: The JavaScript operators `&&` and `||` do not necessarily yield a boolean value as a result.

Comment: Bfff ... I will need to check my entire project :( ... how you suggest to solve this ? (I need to use many times in mi project conditions like this)

Comment: The operators return the actual values from either the left-hand or right-hand side of the operation. They perform the *test* by coercing the values to boolean, but they return the *actual* values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's working correctly.

`(my_string == 'some_string' && my_obj['hash'])` is equal to `"4010f89a05c236cd4f3a5c755..."` which is truthy. This is just fine to use as a conditional in an `if` statement for instance.

You can convert it to an actual boolean too:

```
!!(my_string == 'some_string' && my_obj['hash'])
```

Answer (score 4):

The && operator returns whatever is on the right side of the && whenever both values are true like this:

```js
const foo = 'foo';
const bar = 'bar';

const foobar = foo && bar;
console.log(foobar);
```

This returned result is then in turn coerced into a true of false as the result of the if statement. It is important to realise that the if statement coerces the value into a boolean and the && statement does not.

Answer (score 4):

One option is to use the `in` operator to check to see if a particular key exists in the object. I prefer this method because JavaScript has some really really awful values that are considered falsey, like `0`.

```
console.log((my_string == 'some_string' && ('hash' in my_obj)));
```

Answer (score 1):

&& does not return everytime boolean.

When you use && with string it returns the second value when both are true.
When you use || with string it returns the first value when both are true.

```
let one = "Cat" && "Dog"     
let zwo = "Cat" || "Apple"
```

one returns Dog. two returns Cat

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **ternary operation** and make it return true or false.

Like so:

```
console.log(   (my_string == 'some_string' && my_obj['hash'])   ? true : false );
```

More info here:

- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_operators.asp (search for "Conditional (Ternary) Operator")
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/conditional-ternary-operator-decrement-javascript